# When to use the title "Professor" if employed at different academic positions in different countries

Tags: professorship, titles

I have a curious question. I am employed as a Chair Professor and a Professor of Practise at a recognised University in India and I am also employed as a Lecturer at a recognised University in the UK. In email communications of the respective University, I use different titles to reflect my employed academic position for that respective University.

However, when attending conferences or other academia/research/professional events what title is appropriate to use? (Often times the events ask us to use title that are appropriate)

Can I use the title of 'Professor' at events as that is the academic position in which I am employed in India, but in the UK I'm not employed as a Professor yet?

P.S. At events I represent both the Universities (Indian and U.K.).

Comment: Do you mean formally, say for correspondence, or informally, in conversation?

Comment: @Buffy: I am asking for formal correspondence. For informal correspondence, I usually prefer "Somdip", my first name :P No title required.

Answer (score 5):

You should use the title you hold at the institution which you are primarily representing yourself as being affiliated with.

For example, suppose Anne is a Lecturer in Medicine at at Tsinghua University. Suppose Anne is also a Professor of Medicine at the South Dakota School of Medicine.

If Anne attends a conference and fills out her information, the following would be **inappropriate**:

> Anne Tesfaye, MD PhD
> Professor of Medicine
> Tsinghua University

Instead, she should use the title that matches her stated affiliation:

> Anne Tesfaye, MD PhD
> Lecturer in Medicine
> Tsinghua University

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I usually provide both my affiliations when visiting an event. Which usually will look like: Somdip Dey, Lecturer @ X UK University | Chair Professor of Z @ Y Indian University. However, when asked about the formal title for registration for the event what title can I/should I use in this scenario? Note: I represent both the Universities at the same time at such events (not one or the other).

Comment: @SomdipDey Just use the higher title.